# Order lower matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, tidyr

It would be nice to receive your help.

I have a lower triangle matrix, but I would like to edit the order of the rows, based on my OWN list of names (maybe a vector?).

INPUT

```
   A   C   D   B
A  0   NA  NA  NA
C  13  0   NA  NA
D  14  17  0   NA
B  12  15  16  0
```

OUTPUT

```
  A   B   C   D
A 0   NA  NA  NA
B 12  0   NA  NA
C 13  15  0   NA
D 14  16  17   0
```

I want to recall the order of the rows should be a list provided by me, and NOT any ascending or descending order.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lower.tri` to get a logical matrix where the lower half elements are TRUE and others FALSE, subset the dataset ('v1').  Use this to `order` (`v1[order(v1)]`) and assign it back to the lower triangle of the data

```
v1 <- df1[lower.tri(df1)]
df1[lower.tri(df1)] <- v1[order(v1)]
```

Comment: Hi @ankur, thank you for your response. Could you explain it a little bit? especially in which part I could introduce the list of names (the order I want to display the matrix) in your script?

Comment: @gusa10  I added more explanation

Comment: but isn't that order by acsending or descending? as I mentioned in my post, I would like to be flexible on the order. My matrix has a lot of rows and I would like to order based on my pre-defined list

Comment: @gusa10  If you want it to be reverse, use `decreasing = TRUE` in the `order`.  By default it is `decreasing = TRUE`.  Regarding the pre-defined list, u could use that instead of `order(v1)`.  As I don't know ur pred-defined list and u haven't shown it in the post, u can modify it

Comment: Couldn't I define my own order? I don't want to use decreasing neither increasing.

Comment: @gusa10  Sure, you can have ur order.  Then replace `v1[order(v1)]` to `v1[yourcustomorder]`.  But make sure that the indexes are within the range and extend the whole lower triangle

Comment: Still having errors: names <- c('C','D','B',A'). And then, v1[names]. Am I making it wrong?

Comment: @gusa10 You said that there is a custom index.  you are trying to use it on names which is not right